# Get uploaded KB/MB value of uploaded file field in umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

Trying to get uploaded KB/MB value of uploaded field in umbraco.

The below code works fine if we were getting the file size of the item but i want the file size of the upload field @item.GetPropertyValue("uploadPDF"), how do i do that?

```
    @foreach (var item in selection){

       // Get uploaded file size in MB
       var bytes = Convert.ToInt64(@item.GetPropertyValue<string>("umbracoBytes"));
       var x = ((Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(@bytes) / 1048576, 1)).ToString() + " MB");
       var y = ((Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(@bytes) / 1024, 1)).ToString() + " KB");
       var fileSize = (bytes >= 1048576) ? x : y;

       // Loop through items and iterate 
       var pdf = @item.GetPropertyValue("uploadPDF");

           <div class="full-div">
               <a href="@pdf" target="_blank">
                  <img src="/images/pdf_icon.png" alt="">
                    @item.Name (@fileSize) 
                    // Get the file size of the pdf field instead of the item field
               </a>
           </div>
         }
```

Comment: can you explain the structure of the media type or document type that your `uploadPDF` property is attached to?  If it's on a media type (e.g. `Image`) then is it in addition to the `umbracoFile` property?  The `umbracoBytes` property really only applies to media types, and is used internally by Umbraco in conjunction with the `umbracoFile` property.

Comment: It's an upload property (Umbraco.UploadField), I'm uploading PDF documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using the built-in media types in Umbraco you should be able to get the size from the `umbracoBytes` property as long as you're using either `File` or `Image` media types.

It however sounds like your property is a `Umbraco.UploadField` existing directly on a document type, which means it does not have the file size available.

In your case, I would add a property to your type called: `uploadPDFbytes`, then create a `IApplicationHandler` and hook into the `Saving` event. Then when saving content that stores a PDF file - I would make sure that this handler checks the filesize of the file being saved and puts it in the `uploadPDFbytes` property (pretty similar to what Umbraco is doing to its own media uploads). Now you would be able to get the file size of the uploaded PDF by checking the `uploadPDFbytes` property.